# I have read the article on how to create the Keyword function to automatically place the keywords in PHP

Tags: php

Where do I need to place that keyword info to get the function to grab it dynamically in the stored variables?

```
function get_headers() {
    // here set $title, $description and $keywords according to current page 
    // ....

    // then just generate html
    $html = "<title>$title</title>";
    $html .= "<meta name='description' content='$description' />";
    $html .= "<meta name='keywords' content='$keywords' />";

    return $html;
}
```

I hope thats not too bonehead.  lol

Comment: You say dynamically, but that implies there is some source for the keyword data other than typing it in to this code yourself. What is this source? Are there keywords in a database somewhere? Did you put them in a text file? In other words, where should this "dynamic" information come from?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. Surely the code fragment you posted should suffice?

Answer (score 0):

If your using a function it makes more sense to pass those into the function as arguments:

```
function get_headers($title, $description, $keywords) {

    // then just generate html
    $html = "<title>$title</title>";
    $html .= "<meta name='description' content='$description' />";
    $html .= "<meta name='keywords' content='$keywords' />";

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Maybe with some defaults in case you don't want to specify them all: `get_headers($title = 'default title', $description = 'default desc', etc...)`

Comment: ... a little `htmlspecialchars(..., ENT_QUOTES)` for XSS security?